# Bootstrap - How do I make two grid cols position side by side regardless of grid width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make two divs (bootstrap cols) that I want to render side by side.

I have a width index of 9 for XL, LG, and MD cases but cannot make the oversized divs arrange horizontally despite there being enough space on the parent div to fit (due to each width of 9 adding up to 18).

First of all, is this possible in Bootstrap and if not what css mods need to be incorporated to render the effect?

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          First Container
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          Second Container
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your col-xs from 12 to 6

Comment: the col-sm also

Comment: I need the 12 because I want to occupy full width on small devices.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question wrong the first time. The 2 widths should add up to 12. I think bootstrap uses a 12 col framing.

Comment: Can I, despite that requirement, make the divs align side by side, even if I use css?

Comment: Im sure if you give them unique classes, and target those with css, you can override their default coding.

Answer (score 0):

to render them side by side use CSS code as below `col-xs-offset-2` will make it 2 scales apart from first container

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5 ">
              First Container
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-5 col-xs-offset-2">
              Second Container
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anonymous, my div is too small on the left container.  I am trying to render them (the two divs) as close to 50% each of the parent div.   col-xx-6 or col-xx-5 is too narrow so that is why I tried col-xx-9 which matched the 50% on one of my divs but the other went below the first div.

Comment: if you want them to render side by side only till md-screen then use md in place of xs in my code everywhere that will do the trick